# Unable to change the TextBox value to Uppercase

Tags: jquery

I have having the following code to change the TextBox value to UpperCase. Its working for first two keyup Events only. For example "ab" to "AB". But not changing "abc" to "ABC". I have no clue of what is happening. [jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/XPkfj/24/)

```
<input type="text" class="FrmTextBox" id="Code">
<div id="output">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".FrmTextBox").keyup(function(key){
        $("#output").html($(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase()));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".FrmTextBox").keyup(function (key) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        $("#output").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of html() you can give text
here is the code try it out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".FrmTextBox").keyup(function(key){
        $("#output").text($(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase()));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(elem).val(newValue)` returns a jQuery object and not the value. `$(elem).val()` (without any arguments) returns the value.

If you need to set the value and return it, use: `$(elem).val(newValue).val()`

In your case, this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".FrmTextBox").keyup(function(key){
        $("#output").html($(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase()).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**How about CSS:**

```
input.upper { text-transform: uppercase; }
```